# Stack overflow error in release, but not debug. (ActionScript)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, crash

I have some ActionScript3 code that for some reason only crashes in a stack overflow when compiled for 'Release' mode. The method it crashes in doesn't call any other function and does therefore not recurse in any way.
The weird thing is that when compiled in 'Debug' mode it works perfectly.
The 'Release' mode also starts working if I enable 'Verbose stack traces' in the compiler options. What is this trickery? Is there a bug in the flash compiler when it tries to optimize too much?

---

Edit:

Here is the stack trace:

```
Stacktrace:
VerifyError: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.

    at Extensions::CRunObjectSelection/filterNonQualifierObjects()
    at Extensions::CRunObjectSelection/filterObjects()
    at Extensions::CRunEasing/con_IsObjectMoving()
    at Extensions::CRunEasing/condition()
    at Objects::CExtension/condition()
    at Conditions::CCndExtension/eva2()
    at Conditions::CCndExtension/eva1()
    at Events::CEventProgram/computeEventList()
    at RunLoop::CRun/f_GameLoop()
    at RunLoop::CRun/doRunLoop()
    at Application::CRunApp/loopFrame()
    at Application::CRunApp/playApplication()
    at Application::CRunApp/stepApplication()
```

And here is some of the code referenced in that report:

```
public function selectAll(Oi:int):void
{
    var pObjectInfo:CObjInfo = OiList[Oi];
    pObjectInfo.oilNumOfSelected = pObjectInfo.oilNObjects;
    pObjectInfo.oilListSelected = pObjectInfo.oilObject;
    pObjectInfo.oilEventCount = eventProgram.rh2EventCount;

    var i:int = pObjectInfo.oilObject;
    while(i >= 0)
    {
        var pObject:CObject = ObjectList[i];
        pObject.hoNextSelected = pObject.hoNumNext;
        i = pObject.hoNumNext;
    }
}

public function filterNonQualifierObjects(rdPtr:Object, Oi:int, negate:Boolean, filter:Function):Boolean
{
    var pObjectInfo:CObjInfo = OiList[Oi];
    var hasSelected:Boolean;
    if (pObjectInfo.oilEventCount != eventProgram.rh2EventCount){
        selectAll(Oi);  //The SOL is invalid, must reset.
    }

    //If SOL is empty
    if(pObjectInfo.oilNumOfSelected <= 0){
        return false;
    }

    var firstSelected:int = -1;
    var count:int = 0;
    var current:int = pObjectInfo.oilListSelected;
    var previous:CObject = null;

    while(current >= 0)
    {
        var pObject:CObject = ObjectList[current];
        var filterResult:Boolean = filter(rdPtr, pObject);
        var useObject:Boolean = Boolean(int(filterResult) ^ int(negate));
        hasSelected = Boolean(int(hasSelected) | int(useObject));

        if(useObject)
        {
            if(firstSelected == -1){
                firstSelected = current;
            }

            if(previous != null){
                previous.hoNextSelected = current;
            }

            previous = pObject;
            count++;
        }
        current = pObject.hoNextSelected;
    }
    if(previous != null){
        previous.hoNextSelected = -1;
    }

    pObjectInfo.oilListSelected = firstSelected;
    pObjectInfo.oilNumOfSelected = count;

    return hasSelected;
}
```

Comment: Pretty hard to tell without knowing anything about your code...

Comment: Please share the part of code where this occurs.

Comment: Ditto to the other comments above, but it may also help to post the stack trace or complete error message as well.  You are describing a very general case of something gone wrong.  I would also describe how you are viewing the debug (in Flash?  FB? a webpage?) and how you are viewing the release.

Comment: Whatever the preceding 3 comments said... oh, and also read the [faq]

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. I didn't post the code because it is kinda cryptic when taken out of context. Here is the code used and the stacktrace:
http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/uploads/asCrash.txt

Comment: On looking at the crash report and code, this seems like a memory leak. I would run a `trace()` on the value of `current`. I think you are never getting to the condition that ends the while-loop. What does `hoNextSelected` return, and does it ever get to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be caused by this bug: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-2993

See also this question: [Why does calling this function with more than 2 parameters in Actionscript 3 cause stack overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3350143/256544)

Answer (score 1):

Do you use trace anywhere in your code? There are two possible problems with the trace function. At first, tracing makes a delay at the runtime and influences on asynchronous processes. At second, it is possible that some methods are called in the trace function. This methods can change values of variables.

So you may to remove some traces and check would code crash in release mode.

Comment: I don't use trace anywhere in the code. I posted a the code in a comment to the original post.